# AWS target groups turn unhealthy with no data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a backend server deployed on aws in a single EC2 instance via elastic beanstalk. The server has ip whitelisting and hence does not respond to ALB health checks, so all target groups always remain unhealthy.

According to the [official AWS docs on health checks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-health-checks.html),

> If a target group contains only unhealthy registered targets, the load balancer nodes route requests across its unhealthy targets.

This is what keeps my application running even though the ALB target groups are always unhealthy.

This changed last night and I faced an outage where all requests started getting rejected with 503s for reasons I'm not able to figure out. I was able to get things to work again by provisioning another EC2 instance by increasing minimum capacity of elastic beanstalk.

During the window of the outage, cloudwatch shows there is neither healthy nor unhealthy instances, though nothing actually changed as there was one EC2 instance running for past few months untouched.

[image: cloudwatch no data]

In that gap, I can find metrics on TCP connections though:

[image: connections]

I don't really understand what happened here, can someone explain what or how to debug this?

Comment: Did you have a host in the load balancer during this time period, if it was part of an autoscaling group did it keep removing the instance?

Comment: Nope, no instance added or removed, there was only one instance running for the last few months which never changed, until I intervened. Edit: typo

Comment: Which region? There were some EC2 issues in us-east-1 which required AWS to recover bunch of instances affected.

Comment: This was in ap-south-1